# Unable to detect duplicate using mysql and rename the string

Tags: mysql

I have my schema for Account as follows :

```
AccountID | FileName
```

If the filename repeats i want it to store it as:

```
filename.txt
filename1.txt
filename2.txt
filename3.txt
```

I am currently doing this by checking the number of duplicates by running a query  to check number of duplicates and then renaming the filename in backed and finally running insert query.

Can this whole procedure can be done in one query ?

Comment: So what you want to do is when you insert into `Account`, if the filename exists, you want to rename the filename to a new one? And what is `accountId`'s value?

Comment: Either you need stored procedure in mysql to check and update new coming input against existing filenames or you can do this with your programming language what you would prefer and what (code) you have tried to achieve it so far? can you share that code plz

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single query:

```
Select t.ID, t.Account, z.dupCount
From Filename
Join
   (select Account, Count (*) dupCount
    from filename 
    group By account
    Having Count(*) > 1) z
   On z.account = t.Account
order By dupCount Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

> running a query to check number of duplicates

But the data you have shown us *has* no duplicates.

Yes I get that all the files might originally have been named filename.txt, but unless you store the original name as well then you don't know what it's a duplicate of. A further problem arises when we don't know whether you will ever need to deal with records being deleted - at that point a count becomes useless and the max value isn't going to work either (filename10.txt is less than filename1.txt).

Also consider the case where you've uploaded 11 files named filename.txt. What is going to happen when you try to add a file with an original name of filename1.txt? You can't compare based on the original name - because it's unique - but the derived name conflicts with filename11.txt

You are currently looking for an implementation of the solution you have devised for a problem. The implementation of this solution will be absurdly complex. Really you should looking for a solution which lends itself to an easier implementation, e.g. creating a derived filename by prefixing the supplied filename with the autoincrement id of the MySQL record.